# Want to correct inclination in an aimage in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

[image: iclination to the right in noticed]

In the up is italicized to the right. Is there any way in photoshop to straigten this image ?

Comment: This is about text distortion. But I speak here about image distortion

Comment: You'll use the same tool; the other link is still an image! You might need to do Free Transform on parts of your image and "patch" the rest with the Stamp Tool. There aren't many ways to put an image straight but using these 2 tools.

Comment: @go-me whatabout a skew, you can use the ruler to measure and type in number

Comment: @joojaa That sounds like a smart way to do it, indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Transform > Wrap and use unly the upper section to drag the upper part of the image to the left. Good luck!

Pro tip: Drag some guidelines to those towers to make sure they are straight when you edit the image.